# Cannot make transformedValue called in NSValueTransformer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

There is my implementation of `NSValueTransformer`

```
+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    // some implementation, there is breakpoint
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    // some implementation, there is breakpoint
}
```

I register it in runtime

```
 EncryptionTransformer *transformer = [[EncryptionTransformer alloc] init];
 [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:transformer forName:@"EncryptionTransformer"];
```

I mark my field as *Transformable*

[image]

And there is a property in my MO

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *someData;

@dynamic someData;
```

What am I doing wrong? `transformedValue` is not called.

Comment: Is there any difference if you try to comment the "register runtime part"? Where did you put that part? Instead of using a breakpoint, could you simply do a log at the beginning of both methods? What you see?

Comment: Your setup looks correct. The amount of information you provided us with lets me imagine few options for this behavior - 1) You don't set anything to someData. 2) Not sure, but value transformers may be called on `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` 3) Your attribute type is NSData. So, i assume you are converting NSData to NSData, i never tried it but probably CoreData skips transform while converting NSData to NSData. 4) Like flexaddicted said - try without your 'runtime' part

Comment: @PetroKorienev I've tried do it without runtime - no effect, I should try to check 3-d case. But I need to convert NSData to NSData, I don't know what to do to escape this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some assumptions about your problem in comment above.. I reproduced your setup in test example and found following:

1. Your setup is correct - and no need to setup value transformer in runtime like
   `EncryptionTransformer *transformer = [[EncryptionTransformer alloc] init];
   [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:transformer forName:@"EncryptionTransformer"];`
2. The actual value transformer's transformation method `-(id)transformedValue:` is called after `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`
3. Moreover, if you `NSManagedObjectContext` isn't directly connected to persistent store coordinator (the popular approach provided `out-of-box` in frameworks like MagicalRecord or RestKit) `-(id)transformedValue:` isn't called after `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`. It is called only after `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` on context which is directly connected to persistent store coordinator.
4. For the `-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value` the similar rules are true - it is called only after fetches from persistent store coordinator

Simple code (i use your setup):

```
char *data = "abc";
NSManagedObjectContext *moc =
[(TCDAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
Event *event = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Event class]) inManagedObjectContext:moc];
event.timeStamp = [NSDate date];
event.myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:4];   // no call to -(id)transformedValue:
[moc save:nil];   // called -(id)transformedValue:
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, I do my calls on child contexts only and I don't need to do it on my parent context. I think there is a problem. Am I understanding nested context in wrong way? How can I solve it? And why do they make using Transformer only in parent context.

Comment: Not actually. The key point here is that transformer is called with the save to database. Look, you save on child -> changes propagated to parent. This way changes are propagated through contexts to the root context (connected directly to persistent store coordinator). When you save the root context the changes are committed to the database. And this is the moment, when transformation is actually performed. So, in database you have your data encrypted, in memory (managed object contexts) - decrypted. Not sure, what do you try to achieve, but i think it's ideal situation

Comment: So when I call save: on my child context, changes are not commited to the database? And there is not any reason to call save: on child context?

Comment: I have understood, save on child context does only sync on parent context. Ok, Thank you.

Comment: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ for better understanding of nesting contexts - but it's out of scope of this question, better create new one if something's unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your super clear clarification about the default behavior of magical record (persistent store coordinator). I've searched all over the the magical record document, but can't find a clue how to change this behavior. Maybe you can help?

Comment: AFAIK, There's no way to do this. You should setup your own contexts and use methods that has last parameter "inContext:" of MR